# Howto convert a RGB8888 png into a RGBA8888 png?

Tags: png, rgb, paint.net, ms-paint

Does someone know how to convert RGB8888 png into a RGBA8888 png?

I am using paint.net or paint, but I cant find any way to do so.

Comment: Where would the alpha data come from?

Comment: Can you tell us something more about your efforts? Have you tried to use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_set) (e.g. see [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15308) or [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=7845))? What is your goal? The question is a little broad.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry for beeing inprecise. It is because I do not understand it in general. But it seems to be with alpha value ? I tried to read the file in java and I get this message. I'll try to add the alpha to the png.

Comment: RGB is a 24-bit RGB image, not transparency. RGBA is a 32-bit RGB image WITH transparency. 8-bits per channel (RGBA). I don't know Paint.net at all.. but the extra 8 bits would come from transparency in the image. If there's no transparency, theres no need for a 32-bit RGBA image.